# Python Hex values in ascii encoded string

Tags: python, string, encoding, hex, ascii

I have a problem in python reading a string from a .txt file
File contains these data : \xce\x97 
Encoded in ascii (Similar to "\xce\x97" using a python string)
I want to convert it to UTF-8 encoding

```
file.open("file.txt", "r")
a = file.read() #a = "\\xce\\x97"
file.close()
```

The correct value of this string is : "Η" (Its a greek letter, capital "η")
Ι can use

```
>>>a = b'\xce\x97'
>>>print(a.decode("utf-8"))
>>>Η
```

How can I do it using the varriable a?

Comment: Have you tried specifying `encoding='utf-8'` in your `open`?

Comment: Yes, it prints \xce\x97

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For decoding problems:

```
a = "\\xce\\x97"
print(a.encode().decode('unicode-escape').encode("latin-1").decode('utf-8'))

'Η'
```